# Finite-valued target vector for select_features in tsfresh

Tags: python, feature-selection, tsfresh

I am using tsfresh in Python for a classification problem. The variable to predict can have 5 values (from 0 to 4). I am trying to use select_features to reduce the relevant features in the input. In the documentation I find that "Target vector...can be binary or real-valued" not for finite-valued. Is there a similar function to deal with finite (more than binary) target vectors? Or does it make sense to use select_features (so the target vector is considered as real-valued)?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your data or code, as well as the exact error raised?

Comment: I do not get an error, I do not good results, so I am wondering whether there is a more suitable function or a workaround for finite-valued predictor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably already solved your problem. I will give an answer for other people stumbling upon this question.
The function `select_features(...)` is correct, but only since the merge of [this PR](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/pull/762), which hasn't been released so far. So you would have to use the repo directly instead of pypi. An example doing it can be found in [this tsfresh jupyter notebbok](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/blob/main/notebooks/examples/04%20Multiclass%20Selection%20Example.ipynb).

Before you had to split you multiclass problem into binary problems. That is also described in the above mentioned notebook.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Could you accept the answer then? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is a help page regarding that topic.